# '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples, typeerror

I am using Python3 and have the following code (partial code).

```
tsret = pd.DataFrame(index=tslag.index)  
start_date=datetime.datetime(2011,1,10)

tsret = tsret[tsret.index >= start_date]
```

## tslag in web data from yahoo/google

I have imported pandas and date frame. I am getting the following error

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'datetime.datetime'.

I understand that `tsret.index` is a tuple whereas `start_date` is of type `datetime.datetime`, hence I am not able to compare these two. How do I overcome the error? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is clear from your words, what your problem is but since we do not have a [MCVE], it is harder to solve your problem. Consider going through the link and set up a minfied example of your data.

Comment: what is the result of print(tsret.index[0])?

Comment: What do those indices look like?  You'll have to convert the `datetime` to a tuple.  THere's already a method for this [`datetime.timetuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple), but your indices may not be in the same [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) format